# can't bind to port 8080 with traefik's dashboard

Tags: docker, traefik

I have the following traefik config file:

```
debug = true
logLevel = "DEBUG"

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
    compress = true

  [entryPoints.dashboard]
    address=":81"
    [entryPoints.dashboard.auth]
      [entryPoints.dashboard.auth.basic]
        users = [
          "admin:-------"
        ]

[traefikLog]

[accessLog]

[api]
dashboard = true
entryPoint = "dashboard"

[ping]

[docker]
```

and the following routing in docker-compose:

```
- ‘5080:80’
- ‘5443:443’
- ‘5000:81’
```

this works as exepected and the dashboard is accessible from the outside on port 5000.

The problem arises when I change the dashboard port to 8080 and reflect it in the mapping ('5000:8080')

I get the following errors:

```
level=error msg="Error opening listener listen tcp :8080: bind: address already in use" 
level=fatal msg="Error preparing server: listen tcp :8080: bind: address already in use"
```

The problem is that I don't see 8080 being in use:

```
[root@ns3106050 ~]# lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
sshd      1276   root    3u  IPv4    515      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd      1276   root    4u  IPv6    517      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
dockerd   1277   root    6u  IPv6   5955      0t0  TCP *:2376 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 5425   root    4u  IPv6  24484      0t0  TCP *:5443 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 5436   root    4u  IPv6  24492      0t0  TCP *:5000 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 5447   root    4u  IPv6  22391      0t0  TCP *:5080 (LISTEN)
```

what could I have missed?

Comment: what is the output of `netstat -pant | grep 8080`?

Comment: [root@ns3106050 ~]# netstat -pant | grep 8080 ->
[root@ns3106050 ~]#

Comment: it doesn't return anything

Comment: Is that inside the container or on the host machine? The error comes about because you're trying to bind inside the container to a port that is in use. We therefore need the output of `netstat -pant | grep 8080` inside the container.

Comment: The official traefik docker image *seems* to have disabled shell

Comment: @myol You can use the `:alpine` tag of the docker image to have access to the shell.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you don't have `--api` flag specified for traefik command in docker-compose file. CLI and toml configurations don't work together.